# How to add content to a running web page?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a project that involves conducting and managing online polls. I have a database set up, and a login/sign up page. After logging in, users are directed to the main page, in my case, "index.jsp". On this main page, I want all the current active polls to be displayed (max 5). 
My idea was to have a button, i.e. "Create a new poll", and upon clicking it, the user is redirected to a form where they can create a poll (question and choices) using text fields. Upon clicking submit, the newly created poll should be added on the main page, the "index.jsp" page. And here is where I am stuck. Is it possible to modify and update a page while its running? And if so, how? As in, if a new poll is created, the next user that logs in should be able to see the poll displayed on the main page.

I am using a mix of .jsp, .html files and servlets.

Also, is this a reasonable approach? I thought also about polls being separate from each other. As in, if user goes to */pollno=1, it is able to access poll number one, and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't you get the new poll data from where you received the original 5 polls from?  i'm assuming when you create a new poll you persist it in a database somewhere ... and then retrieve the polls from that location.

Comment: A JSP isn't "running". A JSP is a piece of code on a web server that responds to an HTTP request by generating a dynamic HTML page as a response. Each time you go to the URL of the JSP, the JSP regenerates a new response and sends it back. So, if the JSP goes to the database to find the last 5 polls, it will send back a page with the last 5 polls. You need to learn how HTTP works.

Comment: I should have placed running in quotation marks. I know a JSP isnt running. What I'm trying to do is have the jsp page update with the newly created poll, and this is where I'm stuck. Storing the poll data in a database (i.e. poll number, some sort of ID of the poll to sort them out) and then retrieving it would suffice?

Comment: "I should have placed running in quotation marks." -- It's not too late to do that.  Instead of trying to explain yourself in comments, you can always edit your original question to add information.

Comment: Yes, it would suffice.

Comment: Again, a JSP page doesn't need to update. It' doesn't have any state. Every time you send a request to the JSP, it will get the last 5 polls in the database and return them. Just like if I asked you repeatedly "what time is it?", you would watch your clock every time and tell me the current time.

Comment: Thank you very much JB Nizet!